# How do I duplicate a product in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

This is my problem:

- I have a product set up in my catalogue - it does contain stock
- I want to duplicate the product to use most of the data and create a
  new product, so I 'duplicate' it on the 'products' page of the
  catalogue
- As soon as I have done this the new product (on the
  products page of the catalogue) shows a red circle containing a zero
  in the 'quantity' column (so the product always shows as 'put of stock)

There is nothing I can do to change this stock level - I have tried ALL of the following:

- changing the product 'reference' number
- adding stock in the 'Stock Management' page under the 'Stock' menu  (after doing so the 'Quantity' column on the 'Stock Management' page DOES include the new stock figure, but that stock never gets added to the 'Quantity' column on the 'Products' page of the catalogue)

I'm now stuck !!

This is the detailed set-up of my shop:

- I'm using Advanced Stock Management
- I have a warehouse called 'Warehouse1' (already set-up)
- I have a carrier called 'Carrier1' (already set-up)
- I have a product called 'Product1' (already set-up)
- 'Product1' has been associated with 'Warehouse1' (and 'Carrier1',
  though that isn't stated as being mandatory)
- 'Warehouse1' has been associated with 'Carrier1'
- 'Warehouse1' has been associated with my shop

(i.e. all 'associations' ARE done as defined [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Presenting+the+Stock+Management+Interface))

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Hi Steve. What is your exact presta core version? I tried steps that you described in 1.6.0.11 and for me Qty was succesfully added anywhere except Stock Management "home" page, there columnt Quantity still contains  "-", but in Products all ok.

Comment: Hi Sergii, I'm using v1.6.1.3 (many thanks for looking into this)

Comment: As soon as I go into the 'catalogue' > 'products' page and select the 'duplicate' option (inside the EDIT button) at the right of that product's row, it (i) creates a new copied product and (ii) displays the red circle containing the white zero in the 'quantity' column of the new product's row. I've never seen this red circle in any of the Prestashop docs - presumably it's some kind of warning?

Comment: I think it is just visible warning about stock is 0 in "design style", there is nothing about settings for red circle etc. I'll check 1.6.1.3, but if you have possiility check also previous versions like 1.6.0.11, just I'm not sure that I'll can repeat exactly your case.

Comment: sergii - would you be willing to take 2 mins to take a quick look at my test a/c if I grant you access? if so pls email me at stevepitman*at*gmail.com (many thanks)

Comment: I cheked some settings, you forgot to say that you have multishop with qty sharing enabled, so you may see there warnings: *It is not possible to manage quantities when
You are currently managing all of your shops.
You are currently managing a group of shops where quantities are not shared between every shop in this group.
You are currently managing a shop that is in a group where quantities are shared between every shop in this group.* So, you need to check your multishop settings and do not forget to select shop when you manage qty's

Comment: Thanks Sergii - so to try and test this I (i) removed the Multistore option so I'm back to a single store, (ii) deleted all of the products, (iii) added in ONE new product, called Product A, ensuring it was associated with a carrier and a warehouse, (iv) continued to use Advanced Stock Management, (v) added stock to that product under the Stock>Stock Management menu, (vi) duplicated the product to become Product B, (vii) added stock to Product B so it DOES show stock under menu Stock>Stock Management. AGAIN I have the problem - the new stock in Produt B never shows up in the catalogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

I spotted that when I'd been changing adding in stock to the (new) duplicated product I had "All shops" selected at the the top which meant it didn't work (even though I did want to apply the new stock level to ALL of my shops).

The way around it was to come down a level and select "Default group" in the top menu - that did then work. In hindsight this makes sense, as I read somewhere that the Adv Stock Management only shares across those stores inside a group, not across groups.